# Changing class attribute value before and after the instance one

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how the class/instance variables work in Python.

Setting aside the obvious facts like mutable objects (like lists) defined as class variables are shared between instances etc., I've messed around with something different. No better way to visualize it than an example:

```py
class Foo:
    x = 0


f = Foo()
print(f"f.x = {f.x}")
print(f"id(Foo.x), id(f.x) {id(Foo.x)} {id(f.x)}")

print("Setting Foo.x to 5")
Foo.x = 5
print(f"f.x = {f.x}")
print(f"id(Foo.x), id(f.x) {id(Foo.x)} {id(f.x)}")

print("Setting f.x to 3")
f.x = 3
print(f"f.x = {f.x}")
print(f"id(Foo.x), id(f.x) {id(Foo.x)} {id(f.x)}")

print("Setting Foo.x to 6")
Foo.x = 6
print(f"f.x = {f.x}")
print(f"id(Foo.x), id(f.x) {id(Foo.x)} {id(f.x)}")
```

This is the output:

```sh
f.x = 0
id(Foo.x), id(f.x) 1711594340560 1711594340560
Setting Foo.x to 5
f.x = 5
id(Foo.x), id(f.x) 1711594340720 1711594340720
Setting f.x to 3
f.x = 3
id(Foo.x), id(f.x) 1711594340720 1711594340656
Setting Foo.x to 6
f.x = 3
id(Foo.x), id(f.x) 1711594340752 1711594340656
```

So let's walk it line by line:

1. At first `f.x` will be `0`, obviously
2. Now setting `Foo.x` to `5` changes the `f.x` value to `5` - nothing new here, at least for Python devs
3. `f.x` is set to 3, therefore `f.x` value will be `3`, again correct
4. Now `Foo.x` is being set to `6`, I would expect `f.x` to be changed to `6` as well

I've printed the `id()`s of the attributes to see what's going on. So, what happens is, each time `x` value (on `Foo` or `f`) gets changed, it's a new object, new id. I understand that. But why in the case of first `Foo.x = 5` change (when `Foo.x` and `f.x` have the same ids), the attribute gets updated both in class and the instance? This won't happen again, when these are two separate objects.

I mean the question is this: how does it happen (or how does Python know) that when `Foo.x` and `f.x` are the same immutable object, when I reassign `Foo.x`, both of them will get changed?

Comment: `Foo.x` and `f.x` are two *entirely* separate attributes. If `f` is an instance of `Foo`, then `f.x` *shadows* `Foo.x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance attributes shadow class attributes. Until you executed `f.x = 3`, the expression `f.x` evaluated to `Foo.x`, because `f` did not have an instance attribute named `x`. *After* the assignment, `f.x` resolved to the value of the newly created instance attribute.

There is no way to create or change a class attribute directly via an instance, and creating or changing the value of an instance attribute does not affect a class attribute with the same name.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. Sorry, I've googled poorly, didn't find the question that was linked here, also explains it fully. But "There is no way to create or change a class attribute directly via an instance, and creating or changing the value of an instance attribute does not affect a class attribute with the same name." - unless they are mutable, like lists, right? If I `x` is a list, and I do `f1 = Foo(); f2 = Foo(); f1.x.append(1)`, then `f2.x` will be `[1]`

Comment: There's a distinction between changing an attribute (making it refer to a *different* object) and modifying what the attribute already refers to.